# How to remove Add to Cart button from Related Products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've removed Add to Cart button from Shop and Category pages, but how about Related Products section that is below a product page? The code below doesn't work for that.

```
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
  if( is_product_category() || is_shop()) { 
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 10 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using custom CSS as below. Put it under Appearance -> Customizer -> Custom CSS under your admin panel.

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product a.button {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here’s the code for the same:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
```

The reason being that the ‘Add to Cart’ button is displayed on these two actions.

```php
function woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart()
{
    global $product;
    do_action( 'woocommerce_' . $product->product_type . '_add_to_cart' );
}
```